# Issues with default Navigation Property name in olingo

Tags: olingo

1. Need to change the default Navigation property name to a other name. Default name comes with suffix "Details" and i dont want to have the suffix.
2. Have 2 tables with the relationship one to many and when i call the 2nd table using the navigation property it is not returning data(ie SalesOrder('10243')/SalesOrderItemDetails)

Comment: Please show how are you generating the metadata.

Comment: Do you need the steps

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on the Olingo website about how to refine the metadata: http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jparedefinemetadata.html

You basically have to create a JPA EDM Mapping model XML according to the one shown on the website. There you can specify the NavigationProperty and the mapped name. This XML document must then be set at the ODataJPAContext by calling oDataJPAContext.setJPAEdmNameMappingModel();

Comment: this `oDataJPAContext.setJPAEdmNameMappingModel();` does not exist any more!